# Java Regex match string if the patterns ends with ; or nothing

Tags: java, regex

*[Posting this question because I could not find any question matching my scenario, please point me to the post if this is already discussed, I will delete this post.]*

Trying to create a regex to match string `app=myApp` in long string separated by either `,` or `;`.

My regex fails if the patterns is at end and not terminated by  by either `,` or `;`.

This is the regex I have used: **`[^.][app|APP]=(.*?)[,|;]`** this works for the following strings:

1. `env=prod;app=myApp;app.secure=yes`
2. `app=myApp;app.secure=yes`

But does not work for following:

1. `env=prod;app=myApp`
2. `app=myApp`

Here is my code:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^.][app|APP]=(.*?)[,|;]");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringVar);
 if (matcher.find()) {
      return matcher.group(1);
 }
```

I have also tried:
**`[^.][app|APP]=(.*?)[,|;|$]`**
but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `(?:app|APP)=(.*?)(?=,|;|$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kah3gQ/1/)